# mongoose find({}) doesn't trigger callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to add to mongoose model statics function, which I have defined in another file which looks like ( I extend schema before I create model andit is called)

```
'use strict';


exports.statics = {
    list : function (options, cb) {
        console.log('enter');
        var criteria = options.criteria || {};
        this.findOne(criteria).exec(cb);
    },
}
```

I am calling this with Person.list({}, function(err, persons){/*something*/});
and it enters at list function (enter is printed on screen and then stops). Mongo is running regularly, does anyone know what is a problem,

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your model plugins. I've faced the same problem and in my case, it was an incompatibility of one of the plugins I was using (mongoose-timezone) with mongo 5.

I just removed this plugin and everything worked as expected.